# Execute $(document).ready() after $.load(), is that possible or is there an Alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have page with a form and a table (to show results of the saved data using the form).

The form uses ajax to submit the data, data saved and the table should be reloaded afterwards.

The problem is that the table (which is loaded using AJAX(`$.load`)) is loaded after the execution of `$(document).ready()`. which implies that the table does not have the required functionality.

Is there any approach where i can postpone the execution of `$(document).ready()` until the AJAX finish its loading, or shall i use a complete different approach like using iframe?

below is an example of my problem:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //some code here that needed for the html in table.html e.g. datepicker, chosen, jqueryui, etc 
 });
 <form>
    //Inputs with a button to submit using ajax, where the result is displayed using table.php
 </form>
 <div id="tableOfContent"></div> 
    <script>
       $('#tableOfContent').load("table.php");
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the point of using Ajax here. Why not display the table with simply PHP?

Comment: I don't understand your problem - is the table not loading? Are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

document.ready is called when the HTML of the page has finished loading, there's no two ways about it.

What you can do, however, is use live binding, which will attach handlers to elements that are not yet on the page.

Example:

```
$(".datepicker").live("click", function() { 
    $(this).datepicker();
})
```

Updated for jQuery >1.7 (this is also faster)

```
$("#tableOfContent").on("click", ".datepicker", function() { 
    $(this).datepicker();
})
```

Comment: Please note that live() is deprecated in 1.7 on replaced by [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: but what is there a difference between on() and and bind()

Comment: There is no difference, but `on()` is the new way to do .live, .delegate and .bind actions after 1.7.

Comment: @ManseUK `live()` is not deprecated yet, but is recommended to use `on`/`off` before 1.8+ is released as `live` will be removed.

Comment: @lolwut straight from the live() documentation on jquery -> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated"

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$('#tableOfContent').load("table.php",function(){ 
   //completed load actions here
});
```

But you should note that if you load images, they will not be loaded yet. If that is the case, you can make the contents of table.php initially hidden and do the same again inside for $('#tableOfContent img').load(). This would work for 1 image; multiple images is a bit more complicated, but feel free to ask if that is what you are looking for :)

Comment: images wont be loaded ? what ? this is from the ready docs on jQuery site -> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I can call execute use the call back function. but the problem is that I do not want to execute re-write the docuement.ready code twice. I working on an application where i need to centralise all the JS in one file and thus have one document.ready for all the pages in the website

Answer (score 0):

You can delay the ready event using jQuery.holdReady():

```
$.holdReady(true);
// Do your custom stuff... the document may already be loaded.
$.holdReady(false); // Now the ready event will fire as soon as the DOM is loaded.
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Comment: what happens if you want to manipulate the DOM and its not ready when the function runs ?

Comment: In my experience, holdReady is mostly used to prevent DOMready from firing until a certain AJAX request is completed. DOM manipulation should be done inside a $(document).ready() handler.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready() should be used for scripts that should execute, well, when document is ready.

If you need to execute something after an ajax call, you may write everything within a function and call it with the ajax callback.

```
function what_i_need() {
    // bla bla
}

<script>
   $('#tableOfContent').load("table.php", {}, what_i_need);//code had syntax error; '{)'
</script>
```

I'm not sure. Plus, you can call the function when document is ready too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  what_i_need();
});
```

Comment: You've got a tiny syntax error there: `load("table.php", {),`

Comment: But here you execute the code of what_i_need(), which might cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

Load the table data from within the ready function and use the complete event of the load() function to call the remainder

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     // click bindings etc ..
     $('#tableOfContent').load("table.php",function() {  
        // things to do once the table is loaded
     });
 });
```

[load() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: The problem here is that the functions that i need to execute are common to the whole pages, therefore if i use the callback on success I will have to run the code (the same one in document.ready) twice. Which will cause problems such as:

Comment: continued: bind functionality with a div on click will cause the code to be executed twice

Comment: @malkawi Call the code thats reliant on the data of the date in the call back and the remainder of the code on the $(document).ready() function ... there is no need to call anything twice - add some more code to your question and I will improve my answer

Comment: I will elaborate on my problem, in the document.ready most of the functionalities that are common to the whole app are initiated, for example DIVs (.submit-button) are bind to ajaxSubmit onclick. Therefore if define a function and call it in the document.ready and then call it again in the callback of the $.load the code that is bind with the click is executed twice, therefore the forms are submitted twice on click

Comment: @malkawi i dont mean you have to put everything twice ... put the things the require the table in the table callback and everything else in the ready() function ....

Comment: thanks a lot, so this means that I need to separate the functions that i need to the functions that is needed for the table or I can use iframes, do you think its recommended?

Comment: dont use iFrames - no need ... if you put your functions that are called in your question it will be simple to show you how to arrange them ... comment the ones that require the table to be loaded